SwiftUI/firebase - check user is signed in and display different view
Ok been having a dig around for too long now and can't find a solution to this. Either I'm googling the wrong terms or the info doesn't exist (more likely the former!)
In swift I used the below code in the SceneDelegate func scene... to detect if there is current user and then redirect them to a different view
let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if currentUser != nil {
        let board = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let home = board.instantiateViewController(identifier: "home") //as! UITabBarController
        window?.rootViewController = home
    }

How do you achieve this behaviour in SwiftUI. I've managed to achieve it by publishing this bool in my LoginViewModel (which I'm also using to detect when a user is successfully logged in after completing the login form)...
@Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = false  // Track login status

Then in my ContentView (the first view that loads) I'm observing that bool and added this to the navigation stack
.onAppear {
        // Check if the user is already logged in
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            viewModel.isLoggedIn = true
        }
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.isLoggedIn) {
        TabBarView()
    }

Which does work, but only after fully loading the welcome screen and visibly transitioning the user to my TabBarView. How can I do this so the user goes straight to the TabBarView and never seeing the ContentView.
My first swiftUI app, so likely full noob error. Any help appreciated.

you need to manage this logic in Main view where you handling to show Contentview. like in "@main" struct
